# Reverse mod operation getting bounded number

Tags: arithmetic, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to get the reverse of the mod operation if I just want the first possible number? I mean, if I can bound the initial number.

For example:

I want to do $(x+y) \pmod {10} = z$ ($x$ known, $0\le y\le9$ and, of course, $0\le z\le 9$) and get $y$ having $x, z$ and knowing it is $\pmod {10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write $y=z-x \pmod{10}$.

Comment: I knew it wasn't so hard, but I could think of it. Really thanks.

Comment: There's an error in the formula, it should be: There's an error in this formula, it should be: $y=((z+10)-x )\pmod{10}$. It fails, for example when you have x=598, y=2

Comment: Can't see the failure. Here is what you have: $x=598$ and $z=0$. Therefore $y=0-598=-8=2\pmod{10}$, which is what you expected. Adding 10 is just adding 0 to the result. This seems to be mathematically correct.


On the other hand, if you are using the `%` operator in a programming language it might [not work][1] as the $\pmod$ operation in math, this will depend on the language you are using.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls

Comment: I might be confused, but $2\pmod{10}$ isn't 2? then why $-8=2\pmod{10}$?

Comment: Any number of the form $10k+2$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, is congruent to $2\pmod{10}$. This is the case for example for $k=-1$, and $k=0$. For $k=-1$ we get $10\cdot (-1)+2=-8=2\pmod{10}$ and for $k=0$ we get $10\cdot0+2=2\pmod{10}$. It is just a matter of which representative $\pmod{10}$ is chosen, usually it is elements from $\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ then ones that are chosen.

Comment: Does this rule works only for 2 or any number?

Comment: It works for any integer $r$, $0\leq r \leq 9$. If you are given an integer $a$, you can write $a=10k+r$, with $0\leq r \leq 9$ using [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). Therefore $a=10k+r=r\pmod{10}$.